# Is it acceptable to have a cancel button in Android dialogs?

Tags: android

Android allows you to cancel most dialogs by closing them with the back button, but many of the dialogs in the OS still have a dedicated *Cancel* button. Example:

[image]

Is it always appropriate to have such a button? It looks fine to me, but one could argue that it is a bit redundant and clutters space if a dialog has three buttons (cancel, action #1, action #2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on the context but if the OS is using it then you can use it as well and it's consistent.

[Here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/is-a-cancel-button-necessary-in-a-web-form) there is a similar thread (cancel button in web forms)