# Are "reset" buttons redundant?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, buttons, accessibility, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is a cancel button necessary in a web form?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1042/is-a-cancel-button-necessary-in-a-web-form)

Are form "reset" buttons redundant? If not, why not? Give me a case where they are completey accepted, useful and maybe even encouraged/required?

They are rarely seen nowadays (especially within modern sites). Why?

@PatrickMcElhaney♦ [has said](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/352/clear-all-button-history/355#355):

> `<input type="reset">` was added in HTML 2.0, along with forms in general.
>
> I don't know the reasoning at the time for having a reset button. **It may have been meant as a primitive form of undo**. I'm not sure to what extent user-agents (browsers), particularly text-based user-agents, supported the undo faculties that we take for granted in todays GUIs. Note that a reset button doesn't actually "clear" the fields; it resets them to their initial values.
>
> Initially, I think people were mostly concerned with using HTML correctly and added reset buttons by default without thinking about it. Over time, **the reset button seems to have fallen out of favor**.

If you feel obliged to put one in; does that imply that your form could be more usable?